# Sort search result automaticaly

Tags: 2013, search-results, fast-search

I have created a hyper link in the bottom of each "news" page which goes to `_layouts/15/osssearchresults.aspx`. The reason is I want to show all "News".

So I changed the href of hyperlink to `_layouts/15/osssearchresults.aspx?k=contentType:NewsCT`.
It works and it shows all news.

However they are not sorted based on created date. I thought if I change the query (href) to `?k=contentType:NewsCT AND sortlist='created:descending'` it would work but it didn't. I have tested some other queries but not succeeded yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to append to the url, you can add something like this -

`osssearchresults.aspx#Default={"k":"Amit","o":[{"d":1,"p":"Created"}]}`

Above, k = queryText ; d - can be 0 or 1 for specifying the sorting order ; p - parameter based on which you want to sort. Further  you may look into this [link](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2013/01/09/how-to-sort-search-results-by-query-string-with-the-resultscriptwebpart-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx)

Also if you are using result source for search results, you have the option of sorting under the `Sorting` tab. There you can choose the `Created` field and select the sort order.

Hope that solves your query.

Answer (score 1):

First of you should use SPContentType and not ContentType. For some reason ContentType seems a bit unstable but the "special" SPContentType always works.

In addition to the suggestions by @Sane.Amit you can edit the search result web part and change the sort order drop down values, then uncheck it again as explained in my post: http://techmikael.blogspot.no/2013/06/how-to-change-default-sort-of-search.html

But I tend to go the Result Source way myself. Very flexible and easy to use.